# How to setup cors on IIS with web.config?

Tags: c#, iis, cors

I have a simple server, created with C# (in .NET Core) and react application to work with it.

There's no problems on unit-tests or processing request sent from postman on localhost.

But react application (started with webpack) fails with cors error.

I have no full access to IIS configuration, but I can do something with `web.config`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
            <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
                <remove name="WebDavModule" />
            </modules>
            <httpProtocol>
                <customHeaders>
                    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:1337" />
                    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,OPTIONS" />
                    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
                </customHeaders>
            </httpProtocol>
            <handlers>                
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="GET,POST" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
            </handlers>      
            <aspNetCore processPath=".\myserver.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="OutOfProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

I also tried this way:

```
<system.webServer>
    <cors enabled="true">
        <add origin="*" />
    </cors>
</system.webServer>
```

and

```
<add origin="http://localhost:1337">
    <allowMethods>
        <add method="GET" />
        <add method="POST" />
        <add method="OPTIONS" />         
    </allowMethods>
</add>
```

And I have this in my `program.cs` (works fine on localhost):

```
app.UseCors(builder =>
    {
        builder.SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader()
               .AllowCredentials();
    });
```

But I still get error 503 in react application.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Error 503 is service not avialable.  Make sure the service is running on port 1337.  From a cmd.exe window check the ports using >Netstat -A which will give a list of UDP and TCP ports running.  Port 1337 should be in the listen state.  It is possible a virus checker or firewall is blocking port 1337.

Comment: Checked all few times. No firewall. If i send request from postman - everything fine, but from react app (working on localhost:1337) request to backend fails.

Comment: That 503 response status indicates that the problem doesn't lie in your CORS configuration.

Comment: I see this in browser console:
Response {type: 'cors', url: 'https://serverurl.com', redirected: false, status: 503, ok: false}

And the same request, sent from postman returns correct answer.

Comment: Postman has a control panel which will host all the http headers.  Add the missing headers to your c# code.  Your c# code will work if the headers are exactly the same as Posdtman.

Comment: HTTP status code 503 indicates that the service is unavailable, usually because the server is overloaded or unable to handle the current request. Please enable detailed errors in IIS and provide us with more error information. Or you can try using FRT to view details about the 503 error, which will generate a detailed log file to help you identify the problem. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: If you suspect there is a problem with your CORS configuration, you can inspect the network request in your browser's developer tools to see the headers being sent and received.